# Interface to call AI Models?

Tags: frontend, artificial-intelligence

I'm learning machine learning using SKLearn/Tensorflow.  I want to do a demo.  I want to produce a front-end website to call the models.  However, I don't know much about front-end. I've read a bit and found that I could use HTML, CSS and Javascript.

What is the easiest way to demo AI model using a website ?

Is there way to demo without coding, eg my friend say they use WIX, Wordpress for their website ?  Are these tools able to call the AI model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AI model is just a piece of code. You will need a server to receive and response using the model, and a frontend to nicely display it.
Since you are using python already, i recommend  [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#example) for backend and a simple html js using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) frontend to show the result.
The flow should be like this: frontend have an input, submit input calls to the server, the server call the function to run the model, get result and return back, the frontend gets the result then display.